# What is "kick back argument"?

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

I'm from Chile, and english isn't my natural language. I read in a many papers of Numerical Analysis the expression " using kick back argument" but I don't understand what means.

I will appreciate any example with this "kick back argument" . Thanks .

example: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~demlow/37690.pdf pag 1947 of the document, 10 of PDF

Comment: Agradecería que se remitan a responder la pregunta, las charlas geopolíticas no tienen cabida acá, gracias ;)

Comment: todo tiene cabida aqui papay.

Comment: No me interesa alimentar sentimientos nacionalistas ni chovinismos,  más aún después del circo mediático reciente de la Haya, ya que es un conflicto que corresponde a grandes grupos económicos, y los pueblos peruano y chileno nada y poco tienen que ver en ese circo. He hecho una pregunta matemática que he visto en varios papers de analisis numérico y si no tienen idea respecto de la pregunta mejor que se abstengan de responder.

Comment: seems to be extremely widespread usage. A friend of mine helps his father write up Galerkin method stuff, maybe he will know some early presentations.

Comment: I wrote to him, there is no predicting when he will write back, or whether he or his father know something about the history of the phrase that would lead to a careful textbook-type discussion of the argument. Alright, Dmitry says he never heard of it, very quick email reply. Not sure what to try next...Probably write to some of the authors of articles, ask about discussion of the technique suitable for students. I saw at least one author in Madrid, Spanish would be an option in email

Comment: thanks for your help and comments !

Comment: Now i wrote to Prof. Carrillo at U.A. Barcelona, on the theory that he might know of Spanish sources...I would not expect any answer before Monday. It would help if you wrote me a short email to my gmail address, so i know where to forward his (possible) reply.  http://www.uab.cat/servlet/Satellite/about-the-department/teaching-staff-1210142395450.html